# How do I go about migrating a Xamarin Forms application to GitHub?

Tags: xamarin, github, xamarin.forms

I have a working Forms application and I would like to start using Github to track any changes to the application. Is this something I can do after the project is completed or do I have to do it right from the start? Would appreciate advice on where to start and some basic steps that I should do.

Comment: you can add code to a git repo at any time.  There are numerous existing tutorials that explain how to do this in VS or from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to follow these steps:

1. Create a repository for your code in Github.
2. While creating it, select the option "create a Git Ignore file" and
   select from the drop down the option Visual Studio.
3. Once created download the repository to your local machine.
4. Now, Move all your code files to this recently created folder.
5. You will merge the downloaded cloned repo and your existing code.
6. This will cause Git to detect all changes made (new files added from
   your project & ignore the system files not needed in GitHub).
7. Proceed to do a commit to save the changes.
8. Proceed to do a push of your changes.
9. You will now have your source code in your created repository in
   Github.